Wrong update_url in manifest.json
Our dev team created a chrome extension which is hosted privately (not in Google store). The Update URL in the manifest file is pointing to the DEV URL instead of PRD. which is causing the app not to update since the appid does not exist in the update url.
Can I just replace the manifest file in appdata with a file that has the correct update URL? Or do I have to force a uninstall of the extension and then push it back out via GPO.
